# How to enable user select for some tag using CSS

Tags: css

I have already applied following to by `body` tag which makes my whole body unselectable

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
```

But i want to make only certain tags selectable, lets say, i want #selectme tag to enable selecting text, so i am using following under #selectme CSS but it doesn't seem to work. ANy solutions? I prefer not to include javascript.

```
-webkit-touch-callout:default;
-webkit-user-select:auto;
-khtml-user-select:auto;
-moz-user-select:auto;
-ms-user-select:auto;
user-select:auto;
```

Comment: Try setting the value to `text` instead of `auto`

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6kP/), what browser are you testing on?

Comment: well, i had my 
::selection {
   background: transparent; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
   background: transparent; /* Firefox */
}
turned on. Is there any way to disable transparency in certain tags?

Comment: can you post a fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: In this case, http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6kP/3/ , how do i select selectable.

Comment: You can overwrite the `::selection` value like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6kP/4/), the problem is that there is no way to revert back to the default browser color, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8676276/2049063) for more info. I suggest you don't use the `::selection` selector since it has been removed from the CSS drafts

Answer (score 1):

Try use **Universal Selector** instead of body in css and then embed to your desired element which you want to select...

**Css:-**

```
* {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
}

h1 {
    -moz-user-select: text;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Try this demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/KqJ7R/

Hope this helps you thanks...

Comment: That part was cleared by koala_dev, is there any way to temp disable  ::selection { background: transparent; /* Safari / } ::-moz-selection { background: transparent; / Firefox */ } ?